# Show web part based on permissions

Tags: sharepoint

So, I'm grabbing data from a sharepoint 2007 announcements list, and displaying it on another site. I need to make sure that the web part that I created is not displayed for people who don't have permissions for the site I'm getting the data from. How do I "disable" the web part if a user doesn't have permissions?

I've tried this.enabled = false in the onload() event, didn't work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output) {
    if (i have permissions) {
      base.Render(output);
    }
}
```

And to avoid UnauthorizedAccessException(s), be sure to check if user has appropriate permissions in any other place where you access any webs, lists and data.

Comment: Wont the title of the web part still be displayed on the page? and just no contents rendered?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what you mean by "disable" the Web Part. Your part can just not render any markup if the current user does not have rights to view the Announcements list.

Comment: I mean that I dont want the web part to even show up. currently, if they user does not have permissions it throws a permissions denied error, which I can't have showing up on the homepage of the sharepoint site, I need it to not show the web part at all, like audience targeting.

Comment: Then you would set the Hidden property to true when the user does not have rights to view the Announcements list.

Comment: OK. The set the Hidden property on the Web Part to true when the current user does not have permissions to view the Announcements list.

Answer (score 0):

To hide a web part altogether, set the web part's [`Hidden`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpart.hidden.aspx) property to true. We follow this approach to hide a web part based on the existence/absence of some properties in a user's profile.

A hidden web part is still on the page, and takes part in the page lifecycle, but it's not visible to users. If you're still having problems with permissions errors, try catching the specific exception and using that as a test on whether or not to hide the part.

Certainly there's more elegant ways to checking permissions, but this approach should be quick and easy.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2013. In other version update the id and text accordingly.
You can hide a web part(s) for the users having no permission with this simple jQuery code:

```
$( "td:contains('There are no documents in this view.')" ).parentsUntil( ".ms-webpartzone-cell" ).hide();
```

For example, I have a list view web part on a page. Permissions applied on list. If a user does not have permission then web part show message:

There are no documents in this view.

Now I placed a Script Editor web part on the top of all web parts and inserted this script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
            $( "td:contains('There are no documents in this view.')" ).parentsUntil( ".ms-webpartzone-cell" ).hide();
       });
</script>
```